# Switching to Java 1.8 on openSUSE 13.2

Tags: linux, java, installation, opensuse

I removed the installed version of Java 1.7 using:

```
sudo zypper remove -y java-1_7_0-openjdk java-1_7_0-openjdk-devel java-1_7_0-openjdk-plugin
```

Then installed Java 1.8:

```
sudo zypper install -y java-1_8_0-openjdk java-1_8_0-openjdk-devel java-1_8_0-openjdk-plugin
```

But when I run `java -version` I get:

```
java version "1.7.0_71"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea 2.5.3) (suse-1.1-x86_64)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.65-b04, mixed mode)
```

Am I missing a symbolic link somewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would be better as a comment, but I don't have that privilege.

Do you have a proprietary Java package?  Did you re-logon?  Check what is installed using `sudo zypper search -i java`.  You should be able to see whatever is providing java version 1.7 and remove that package.  It is possible to manually install proprietary java packages, and indeed there are manually-created symlinks in the instructions (which I have never successfully implemented) but I would think finding and removing the package providing 1.7 would be the place to start in this case.

Comment: I had to uninstall `java-1_7_0-openjdk-headless`. Your answer this led me to this.  Thanks.